# React Js & ASP.Net Webforms - Navigation between apps

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, redirect, webforms, navigation

I am currently working in a new version of a Dashboard application in React with an API in the back. The old one is a site that was made with ASP.NET WebForms technology.

We are not going to migrate all the sections at once, so we are working on phases. We need to achieve navigation between both systems without problems.

Our main issue was cross-site authentication but we were able to solve it pretty fast. Then we started working on navigation, going from the new system to the old one works fine but the problem is when you are at old system and you want to go a new section of the React App. It always redirects you to the last page you visited instead of redirecting to the one you are pointing. I think its something related to the history of React, based on what I was reading.

I'm pretty much new with React so I don't know where to start. We are currently using "connected-react-router" for Routing and here there is code from the App.js file (I dont know if it is useful but I have characters limitation while adding content to the body):

```
import React from "react";
import { ConnectedRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import numeral from "numeral";

import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

import routes from "./routes";
import Layout from "./components/layout";
import Notifications from "./components/globalNotifications";

import es_locale from "../configs/es_locale";
numeral.register("locale", "es", es_locale);
numeral.locale("es");

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Layout>
        <Notifications></Notifications>
        {routes}
      </Layout>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Let me know if you need more code to guide me.

Thank you.